# Sed command to change a string at only desired place

Tags: bash, sed, azure-devops, devops

I want to replace a string from a file using `sed` in bash script, but that string is present at multiple places in that file.

Is there any way to replace the string using a WHERE clause so I can replace the string only where I want?

Using a line number won't work because I need a script that is more flexible than that allows.  Here what I'm trying to do.

I stored the desired piece of code in a variable. Can I use that variable in a `sed` command?  For example,

```
sed -i "s/condition: succeeded('Fair_PreProd')/condition: succeeded('Fair_UAT')/g" $folder_path/$file_name
```

Here is the original file:

```
-stage: Moto_Dev
dependsOn: Build
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isDevelop, true))

- stage: Unity_Dev
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isUnityDevelop, true))

- stage: QA
  dependsOn: Dev
  condition: succeeded('Dev')

- stage: UAT
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isStaging, true))
```

There are 3 places where `dependsOn: Build` is present. I want to replace only the one in the `-stage:MotoDev` section. How can I do that?

Comment: There's no where clause in sed, but there are multiple tools you could leverage. Whithout knowing more about your context (what criteria do you use to decide which occurence of your search token needs to be replaced) we have no way of knowing which would be useful to you though

Comment: The `/test/` command in sed is the closer to a where clause. If a line matches the pattern it contains, the following command or group of commands will be executed on that line

Comment: Letme give you an example. Look at my code, where I refer a file, Suppose that file contains 5 lines. like 
block1{
a=c
}
block2{
v=c
}
block3{
w=c
}
block4{
a=c
}
block5{
a=c
}
here you can see there are 3 places where a=c is present. What i want to replace only block 4 a=c.  What'll be the process to do that

Comment: Two simple ways : include block4 in your `s`ubstitution command, but do not use it in your replacement pattern, e.g. `sed 's/block4{ \(a\)=\(c\) }/found \1 : \2/g'` ([test](https://ideone.com/xNNR9W)). Or use `/test/` to execute conditionally your substitution, e.g. `sed '/block4/s/{ a=c }/ found/'` ([test](https://ideone.com/utzWDm))

Comment: @Aaron nope, thats not the generic way, what if the block4 contains 100 lines of code, Would you add all of them in your sed command.

Comment: It was just an example.

Comment: If you use GNU sed: slurp the whole file in and use the occurrence integer in the substitution command. e.g. `sed -zi 's/pattern/replacement/2' file` where 2 is the second occurrence of `pattern`.

Comment: @Muhammad_Bilal stop giving examples if you want an answer that tailors to your exact case. If block4 is instead 100 lines of code, you'll want to use test in conjunction with a goto-based loop and your susbtitution, e.g. something that detects the start of those 100 lines then searches for both the text you want to substitute (in which case it performs the substitution) and the end of those 100 lines (in which case it stops searching for the text to substitute).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can test our solutions against your test scenario.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-hooks-f2ndro?file=/README.md


This is my case, its basically a code for Azure-pipeline. I just wanna replace the DependOn variabe value, from Build to TEST. But using sed, it replaces everywhere. I only want to replace the value for - stage: UAT.

Comment: @Muhammad_Bilal, put that input and explanation in the question, in place of the misleading example that's there now.  Please remember that one of SO's objectives is to have question & answer pairs that remain understandable and meaningful indefinitely.  Questions that depend centrally on external resources conflict with that objective.  To some extent, so do questions where essential information is presented only in comments.

Comment: Don't put the text in a (probably ephemeral) link off-site.  Include the sample text directly in the question, in between a line containing `\`\`\`none` and one containing `\`\`\``.

Comment: Your question shows a sed script that's trying to replace `condition: succeeded('Fair_PreProd')` but then states you want to replace `dependsOn: Build` instead (`There are 3 places where dependsOn: Build is present. I want to replace only the one...`). You also said `I stored the desired piece of code in a variable` but it's not clear what you mean by that (the sed script?) and there's no indication of a variable in your example. Please [edit] your question to clearly and consistently state what you're trying to do and add the expected output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to replace the string using a WHERE clause so I can replace the string only where I want?

`sed` does not have SQL-style `WHERE` clauses, but commands can have "addresses" that define subsets of input lines to operate upon.  These can take several forms.  Regular expressions are perhaps the most common, but there are also line numbers, and a couple of special forms.  You can also have inclusive *ranges* built from simple addresses.  An address range would be a reasonably good way to address the problem you present.

For example,

```
sed -i '/^\s*-\s*stage:\s*Moto_Dev/,/^\s*-/ s/dependsOn: Build/dependsOn: Test/' input
```

Explanation:

- The `-i` command-line flag tells `sed` to work "in-place", which really means that it will replace the original file with one containing `sed`'s output.
- The `/^\s*-\s*stage:\s*Moto_Dev/,/^\s*-/` is a range address, consisting of a regex for the range start (`/^\s*-\s*stage:\s*MotoDev/`) and one for the range end (`/^\s*-/`).

  - `/^\s*-\s*stage:\s*Moto_Dev/` matches the beginning of the section in which you want the change to be made, with some flexibility around the exact amount of whitespace at certain positions.  For brevity and clarity, it uses `\s` to represent a single space or tab character.  That is a GNU extension, but if you cannot depend on GNU `sed` then there are other ways to express the same thing.
  - `/^\s*-/` matches the beginning of the next section, *as you have presented the input*.  It could be made more specific if it were necessary to be more selective.
    The range includes its endpoints, but that does not appear to be a problem for the task at hand.
- There is only one such range in the input presented, and that range contains the line you want to modify.  The specified substitution, `s/dependsOn: Build/dependsOn: Test/`, is performed on each line in the range, but only the one contains a match to be replaced.  All others in the range will be unaffected.
- No commands at all are specified for lines outside the range, so they too will be unaffected.

---

You also asked,

> I stored the desired piece of code in a variable. Can I use that
> variable in a `sed` command? For example,
>
> ```
> sed -i "s/condition: succeeded('Fair_PreProd')/condition: succeeded('Fair_UAT')/g" $folder_path/$file_name
> ```

`sed` does not expand shell-style parameter references, but you don't need it to do.  The variable references in that command are expanded by the shell itself, before it executes the resulting command, so

- yes, you may use them, and
- it's not a question of using shell variables with `sed` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting an `awk` solution that reads `bash` variables.

`filter` : An `awk` [RegExp](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) filtering correct lines.

`target`  : An `awk` [RegExp](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) to identify the string to be replaced

`replacement:`  A string **not RegExp** to replace target RegExp.

With provided example:

```
awk '$0~filter && $0~target{gsub(target,replacement)}1' filter="block4" target="a=c" replacement="this = that" input.file
# same command, less readable, but shorter:
awk '$0~f && $0~t{gsub(t,r)}1' f="block4" t="a=c" r="this = that" input.file
```

#### Advantages of this approach:

- More flexible than `sed`.
- Generic: can add more filters and filtering logic.

#### Disadvantages of this approach:

- Cannot do in-place replacement on the input file. Like `sed -i`
- Therefore need to specify all files explicitly one by one.

#### sample output:

```
awk '$0~filter && $0~target{gsub(target,replacement)}1' filter="block4" target="a=c" replacement="this = that" input.1.txt 
block1{ a=c } 
block2{ v=c }
block3{ w=c }
block4{ this = that }
block5{ a=c }
```

Comment: It was kinda hard to get the OP to be clear about what they really wanted. However, well before this answer was posted, they had expressed in comments that the example on which this answer is based was not representative of the problem, and that a solution depending on matching `block4` was not satisfactory.